# Syntax error or access violation Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

i have use this query in my controller

```
DB::insert(DB::raw( "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 ENGINE=MEMORY AS (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, 0 AS Amount FROM coa a);") );

    DB::insert("INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, SUM(b.ar) AS Amount FROM coa a, jurnal b WHERE a.name=b.ar_coa);
        INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, SUM(b.terima_cicilan) AS Amount FROM coa a, jurnal b WHERE a.name=b.terima_cicilan_coa);
        INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, SUM(b.bunga) AS Amount FROM coa a, jurnal b WHERE a.name=b.bunga_coa);
        INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT b.account AS Account, b.name AS Account_Name, SUM(((a.nilai_pinjaman*a.biaya_admin)/100)) AS Amount FROM ar a, coa b WHERE b.name='PENDAPATAN ADMINISTRASI');");

    $report = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT Account,Account_Name,SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM temp1 GROUP BY Account;"));
```

in phpmyadmin that query showing

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 ENGINE=MEMORY 
AS (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, 0 AS Amount FROM coa a);
INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, SUM(b.ar) AS Amount FROM coa a, jurnal b WHERE a.name=b.ar_coa);
INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, SUM(b.terima_cicilan) AS Amount FROM coa a, jurnal b WHERE a.name=b.terima_cicilan_coa);
INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT a.account AS Account, a.name AS Account_Name, SUM(b.bunga) AS Amount FROM coa a, jurnal b WHERE a.name=b.bunga_coa);
INSERT INTO temp1 (SELECT b.account AS Account, b.name AS Account_Name, SUM(((a.nilai_pinjaman*a.biaya_admin)/100)) AS Amount FROM ar a, coa b WHERE b.name='PENDAPATAN ADMINISTRASI');
SELECT Account,Account_Name,SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM temp1 GROUP BY Account;
```

like this

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31YMV.png)

anything wrong with my query or my code? coz only in laravel cant execute that query

Comment: Do you have any TRIGGER in that table?

Comment: no i dont have any TRIGGER or procedure